# Estimate current produced by an IR photodiode on a typical sunny day

Tags: current, solar-cell, infrared, photodiode

How can I estimate or calculate the current which would be generated by an infra-red photodiode (eg. Osram BPW 34 FAS) on a typical sunny day ?

Comment: First, there is neither a typical day, nor is there a typical diode. Secondly, they are not made for that, so nobody does specifications. Additionally, at what time of the day, and how do you hold it? In short: measure it yourself.

Comment: I think it's a good question actually, although the answer may not be what you want to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photodiode data sheet gives you clues. For instance it says that the current produced from a light power of 1 mW per sq cm is typically 50 uA and no lower than 40 uA. Then comes the small print i.e. this is specifically at a colour of 870 nm and with a reverse bias on the diode of 5V.

Then there are more things to consider: -

[image]

The peak spectral response is about 870 nm but it also works quite well over the range 750 nm to 1060 nm (30% output levels). You then have to look into what specrum normal sunlight produces and calculate the "useful" power on a sunny day across this range colours. You can probably make a half decent estimate by using the 30% limits. Anyway sunlight looks like this: -

[image]

And across the range 750 nm to 1060 nm you could say it averages out at about 0.75 W per sq meter per nano metre but you'll need to check what time of day it is and how far from the equator you are to get the true picture.

Anyway, once you do all of that and assuming the figure is still 0.75 W per sq meter per nano metre, mulitply by (1060-750) to get watts per sq metre (232 W per sq metre). This is 23 mW per sq cm so you might expect to get about 1.2 mA.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer; I was expecting something like a few micro-amps. If I understand correctly, the estimate is in principle an integral over lambda of Irradiance multiplied by the relative spectral sensitivity: Int[I(l) * Srel(l)*0.65*dl].
l – lambda [nm],
I(l) - irradiance [W/m2/nm],
S(l) - relative spectral sensitivity [%], integral goes from 0 to inf+.

If I would try to build an improvised infra-red data transfer device for outside use with the above photodiode and an IR LED this means that there would be a high background current signal, right?

Comment: No it doesn't because after your front end amplifier you use a high pass filter to block static or slow moving signals due to ambient light.

Answer (score 0):

Given two sources: [the datasheet](http://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic8/00100764_0.pdf) and NASA: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/Numbers/Math/Mathematical_Thinking/sun12.htm

NASA say "At the earth's surface, the nominal value of the solar constant is 137 mW/cm2. This value corresponds to high noon with the sun directly overhead" and go on to discuss derating it for other latitudes. I'm therefore going to use 50mW/cm^2 as a basis for estimating.

The datasheet gives a number of 50μA for an illuminance of 1mW/cm^2 at the top. There's also a log-log chart on page 4 that suggests that it's linear. So maybe you'd get 2.5mA for 50mW/cm^2? But that's also beyond the line on the chart and far above the nominal value. I can't see a maximum value listed in the datasheet.

And I've just realised that the datasheet specifies for a single IR wavelength, while the NASA figure is for all solar radiation. So there's a serious spectral efficiency problem. Maybe we should treat it as an inefficient solar cell and apply a derate to 10%, giving you a couple of hundred microamps. That sounds reasonable.